# Location accuracy remains low using GPS

Tags: android, gps, location

I have the following code in main activity:

```
LocationManager mlocMan = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);                    

if (mlocMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {                      
   LocationListener mlocListener = new LocationManagerHelper(...);
   mlocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,mlocListener);
}
```

In the location listener I have this: (theAccuracy was initialized to -1)

```
if (theAccuracy == -1 || theAccuracy > loc.getAccuracy()) {
   theAccuracy = Math.round(loc.getAccuracy());
   latitude = loc.getLatitude();
   longitude = loc.getLongitude();        
}
updateTimes++;
if (updateTimes == 3) {
   mLocMan.removeUpdates(this);
   updateTimes = 0;
   //get address for location
   theAccuracy = -1;
}
```

Meaning, after 3 location updates from the GPS, take the best accurate location and get its address. On the emulator I get fixed accuracy of 20m (I send long/lat using DDMS) but that's not real life so I tried with my device and while the very first time (3 requests) gave me the exact address (on the spot) with 40m accuracy, the next ones were sometimes more accurate but the address was nearby. The best accuracy I got was 29m (happened once) most of the times it's above 30. Is this a problem of my GPS (LG G3) or is there any other idea that can make things more accurate after 3-4-5 requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few reasons:

1. Your emulator doesn't have actual gps hardware, so it's probably using your ip address, so that's why it seems fixed.
2. GPS hardware on your phone has to warm up a bit.  Set the frequency of polling up for a bit (1 update a second, or half-second), and let it run for a few seconds, before taking measurements that count.
3. The location manager supports both hardware and network lookups (wifi / celltowers).  Not sure how to set provider to just your phone's hardware, but if you use the googlePlayServices gps client (LocationClient), it's quite simple:

   mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
     mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
     mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
4. You're probably testing at your computer in doors.  Buildings definitely effect gps accuracy.

Comment: 1. the emulator is, ofcourse, not the real life

2. so in minTime param you recommend I should put 1 instead of 0? when you say warm up you mean from the time I turned on the GPS or from my first request?

3. Google play services was inaccurate as the regular request but weighs a lot more with no noticeable benefits. I don't need constant location request so it's not the good for my needs.

4. I'm standing near the window of my house, ironically, the first try gave me perfect result, the next ones...well... less perfect.

Comment: 1. By warm up i mean spam some gps requests, time since the first request isn't the benchmark.  2. I can't tell you whether being near a window is good or bad.  GPS is calculated as the delta between two satellites, if one satellite has a clear line through your window, and the other goes through a wall, it's probably worse than having both go through walls.  3. With google client there is very noticeable convergence from repeated requests.  Whether that's all due to warm up or if there's also an internal convergence algorithm, I don't know.

Comment: I will try to check it outdoors. In the meantime, do you recommend I should ask for more than 3 requests? What minTime do you recommend me to set?

Comment: In my app, on an S5, I have a geotag feature, from cold (gps off), it takes up to 10 seconds for max convergence polling every 0.5 seconds or so.  I get about 2m accuracy at max convergence outside, but for the first second or two the accuracy is as bad a 96m (indoors, at computer).  After about 4-5 seconds its almost always under 10m.